# Problem with initramfs

Tags: boot, kernel, initramfs

I'm trying to reinstall something on my new kernel of Ubuntu 16.04 system. 
And I accidentally tried the command:
sudo update initramfs -u
Since then,
my computer could not boot correctly anymore. Every time, it will enter the busybox, just like:

> BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
>   enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
>
> (initramfs)

More importantly, I could not type in anything under this circumstance.

Right now, I am able to use my computer via another kernel. But does anyone have some good ideas to fix my issue? Thanks.

Here is the output of `ls -al /boot`

```
total 158540  
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Apr  7 12:28 .  
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root     4096 Apr  7 07:01 ..  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217286 Apr  5  2019 config-4.15.0-48-generic  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217465 Feb 28 12:24 config-4.15.0-91-generic  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217465 Apr  1 01:44 config-4.15.0-96-generic   
drwx------  3 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi  
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Apr  7 12:30 grub  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55577646 Aug 28  2019 initrd.img-4.15.0-48-generic  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 56163066 Mar 18 06:25 initrd.img-4.15.0-91-generic  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 12625827 Apr  7 12:28 initrd.img-4.15.0-96-generic   
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin  
-rw-------  1 root root  4051368 Apr  5  2019 System.map-4.15.0-48-generic  
-rw-------  1 root root  4067536 Feb 28 12:24 System.map-4.15.0-91-generic  
-rw-------  1 root root  4068326 Apr  1 01:44 System.map-4.15.0-96-generic  
-rw-------  1 root root  8141400 Apr  8  2019 vmlinuz-4.15.0-48-generic  
-rw-------  1 root root  8193432 Mar  1 05:28 vmlinuz-4.15.0-91-generic  
-rw-------  1 root root  8191544 Apr  6 12:08 vmlinuz-4.15.0-96-generic
```

I tried `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.15.0-96-generic`
but it did not help.

[my terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvE8E.png)

The updated output of `ls -al /boot`:

total 158540

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Apr  7 16:25 .  
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root     4096 Apr  7 07:01 ..  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217286 Apr  5  2019 config-4.15.0-48-generic  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217465 Feb 28 12:24 config-4.15.0-91-generic  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217465 Apr  1 01:44 config-4.15.0-96-generic  
drwx------  3 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi  
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Apr  7 12:30 grub  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55577646 Aug 28  2019 initrd.img-4.15.0-48-generic  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 56163066 Mar 18 06:25 initrd.img-4.15.0-91-generic  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 12625839 Apr  7 16:25 initrd.img-4.15.0-96-generic  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin  
-rw-------  1 root root  4051368 Apr  5  2019 System.map-4.15.0-48-generic  
-rw-------  1 root root  4067536 Feb 28 12:24 System.map-4.15.0-91-generic  
-rw-------  1 root root  4068326 Apr  1 01:44 System.map-4.15.0-96-generic  
-rw-------  1 root root  8141400 Apr  8  2019 vmlinuz-4.15.0-48-generic  
-rw-------  1 root root  8193432 Mar  1 05:28 vmlinuz-4.15.0-91-generic  
-rw-------  1 root root  8191544 Apr  6 12:08 vmlinuz-4.15.0-96-generic
```

Comment: Boot to a bootable kernel, and type `ls -al /boot` and edit that output into your question, and I'll see if I can help. Why did you do the update-initramfs command? What were you trying to reinstall on your kernel? Start commands to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Hi heynnema, thanks for the reply. I just attached the output in my question.  It's a long story why I tried update-initramfs command. My Nvidia driver crashed and I tried to reinstall it. However, there was a compiler issue with my installation file. I searched on the Internet and found an answer which told me to use that command. But I do not remember exactly what the command is used for.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `initrd.img-4.15.0-96-generic` file is corrupt. And you can see that the file size is quite different from the -48 and -91 versions.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 55577646 Aug 28  2019 initrd.img-4.15.0-48-generic  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 56163066 Mar 18 06:25 initrd.img-4.15.0-91-generic  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 12625827 Apr  7 12:28 initrd.img-4.15.0-96-generic
```

To fix:

In `terminal`...

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.15.0-96-generic
```

Then do...

```
ls -al /boot/initrd*
```

And compare file sizes. They should be close. If they are, try and reboot to the -96 kernel, and it should boot.

Comment: Hi heynnema, thanks for the answer. I tried your commands. But it seemed that the size did not change. It was wired to me.  I attached the screenshot in my question. Could you take a look?

Comment: @ClarkLin I don't understand "*It was wired to me.*". Also, show me the entire `ls -al /boot` again. Copy/paste the output as an edit to your question, like the first time that you did that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks,  I have attached the new output. I said "It was wired to me" because I believed you had found the problem and the command should work but it did not.

Comment: Yes, that should have fixed it. The file is 1/4 the size it should be. When you say "*I'm trying to reinstall something on my new kernel of Ubuntu 16.04 system.*" what exactly do you mean? I also assume that -96 didn't boot, correct?

Comment: Yep, you're right. The issue is with my -96 kernel. As I said in my previous comment, I tried many times to reinstall the Nvidia driver in that kernel. I eventually gave up and turned to my -91 kernel. I remembered that I also tried ```sudo apt-get purge Nvidia*``` before. I'm not sure if that is related to this issue.

Comment: Well, you can try this... `dpkg -l linux-*96* | grep ii` when booted to -91 and this will give a list of 5 packages that are the -96 update. Uninstall them, and make sure that `/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-96-generic` is gone, then do a `Software Updater` and try and upgrade back up again. No guarantees. `sudo apt-get purge package_name` to uninstall.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I will try it later. I also intended to reinstall this kernel.

Comment: @ClarkLin Let me know how you make out!

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thank you so much. I'll install them later.

Comment: @ClarkLin Are you running on the -96 kernel now?

Comment: Not yet. I do not want to mess with it right now. A new kernel does not make sense to me.